# Projecting 3D points in 2D plane

Tags: language-agnostic, linear-algebra, projection

I have noisy 3D point cloud `[x,y,z]` plane for which, I fit a 2D plane `(z = ax+by+c)` by computing the coefficients [a,b,c] using least-squares. How can I project the points `[x,y,z]` onto this plane. I somewhat understand the math behind this but I am unsure how to program this in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to project a point onto a plane in 3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605556/how-to-project-a-point-onto-a-plane-in-3d)

Comment: Unless your points were specifically measured as heights, a better way to fit your plane is with principal component analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).  The smallest eigenvector of the covariance matrix is the best normal vector for the plane, which should pass through the mean point.